# Parallel.ForEach - Working With Lists inside ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, .net-4.0, parallel.foreach

i am so confused about Parallel.ForEach.
would you please help me to rewrite the codes below with Parallel.ForEach :

```
    #region Register

    private void btnStartRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
        {
            btnStartRegister.Enabled = false;
            lblStatusOfaccMValue.Text = "Canceling...";
            backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            txtLogInRegister.Text = string.Empty;
            btnStartRegister.Text = "Cancel";
            lblUserCreatedCountValue.Text = "---";
            lblStatusOfaccMValue.Text = "Running...";

            backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(0));

        int UsersCount = int.Parse(txtUsersCount.Text);
        UsersCreatedCount_Step = 0;
        string path = Application.StartupPath;
        string accfilePath = path + @"\acc.txt";
        string logfilePath = path + @"\log.txt";
        string Ok_ip_port = string.Empty;
        string[] Separator = new string[] { "__" };
        int list_lines_acc_Current = -1;

        string[] lines_acc = File.ReadAllLines(accfilePath);
        List<string> list_lines_acc = new List<string>(lines_acc);
        List<string> list_lines_acc_new = new List<string>(list_lines_acc);

        foreach (string line_acc in list_lines_acc)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }

            list_lines_acc_Current++;
            string[] line_acc_ar = line_acc.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (line_acc_ar.Length == 3)
            {
                string username = line_acc_ar[0];
                string password = line_acc_ar[1];
                string email = line_acc_ar[2];
                string[] email_ar = email.Split('@');
                email = email_ar[0] + "%40" + email_ar[1];


                list_lines_acc_new[list_lines_acc_Current] += "__" + txtSuffixURL.Text + "__" + txtServerNumber.Text + "__" + "127.0.0.1:2222";

                try
                {
                    bool[] RegisterMethod_res = RegisterMethod(bla bla bla);
                    bool failed = RegisterMethod_res[0];
                    bool world_full = RegisterMethod_res[1];
                    if (!failed)
                    {
                        UsersCreatedCount_Step++;
                        backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(UsersCreatedCount_Step * (100.0 / UsersCount)));
                        list_lines_acc_new[list_lines_acc_Current] += "__" + "Y";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (world_full)
                        {
                            list_lines_acc_new[list_lines_acc_Current] += "__" + "N";
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            list_lines_acc_new[list_lines_acc_Current] += "__" + "N";
                        }
                    }

                    File.WriteAllLines(accfilePath, list_lines_acc_new.ToArray());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    list_lines_acc_new[list_lines_acc_Current] += "__" + "N";

                    File.WriteAllLines(accfilePath, list_lines_acc_new.ToArray());
                }

                if (UsersCount == UsersCreatedCount_Step)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(accfilePath, list_lines_acc_new.ToArray());
    }

    private bool[] RegisterMethod()
    {
        bla bla bla
        ...
        ...
        return RegisterMethod_res;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblUserCreatedCountValue.Text = UsersCreatedCount_Step.ToString();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnStartRegister.Text = "Start Register";
        btnStartRegister.Enabled = true;

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            return;
        }
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            lblStatusOfaccMValue.Text = "Cancelled...";
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatusOfaccMValue.Text = "Completed";
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

i want to replace `foreach (string line_acc in list_lines_acc)` line with `Parallel.ForEach`.
i could n't do that...
as you see there is an acc file (**acc.txt**) for write and some lists (**list_lines_acc** + **list_lines_acc_new**) for read and write.
always there is a problem about them in parallel mode.
**EDIT :**
problem is about these lines ->

```
        if (UsersCount == UsersCreatedCount_Step)
        {
            break;
        }
```

i want to stop that for in that condition.
but i do n't know how does `UsersCreatedCount_Step` work in parallel mode?

would be really appreciate for some help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us only the method where you have the `foreach`, not the entire class.

Comment: but i think the other parts are necessary.  i want to tell you i am using backgroundworker and so how can i stop that parallel.foreach after hitting cancel button.

Comment: Tudor is right, focus the question. This is almost unreadable. And as always: Describe _"there is a problem about them in parallel mode"_. What problems?

Comment: If you want to know "how to stop a Parallel.ForEach()" then ask that, with about 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it can be done safely. There are a bunch of problems here, including the fact that you are trying to write to the same file from multiple threads:

```
File.WriteAllLines(accfilePath, list_lines_acc_new.ToArray());
```

That part will not only need a lock, but will also degrade performance if you have a mechanical disk.

Comment: so what is your suggestion? (thanks for edit and answer)

Comment: @MoonLight: My suggestion is to think first if you really need parallelism in this case, since it seems pretty messy to do it correctly. Do you really need this code to be faster?

Comment: Actually it doesn't need a lock. But it will overwrite. `AppendAllLines()` could do it.

Comment: is there a way to debug Parallel.ForEach? (with regular debug we can not understand anything).

Comment: also is there a way to force that Parallel.ForEach to use 2 threads every time not more.mean i want index 1 & 2 together. after that index 3 & 4 together and go on.  but without that we have some random indexes together and so we can not control parallel.ForEach.